# Tengo una duda en una funcion js

Tags: javascript

```js
function resta(numr, numr1, resultador) {

    resultador.value = (numr - numr1);
  }


function calculo(cantidad, precio, inputtext, totaltext) {

  gndtotal = totaltext.value - inputtext.value;


  subtotal = (precio * cantidad);
  inputtext.value = subtotal;

  total = eval(gndtotal);
  totaltext.value = total + subtotal;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr id="panela">
  <td>
    <label class="title">Panela:</label><br>
    <label class="num">5</label>
  </td>

  <td>
    <input type="hidden" id="PanelaIn" name="PanelaIn" value="<?php echo $ver[3];  ?>">

    <input type="number"
      class="form-control form-control-lg" 
      id="Panela" name="Panela" placeholder="Saldo"
      required onChange="resta(PanelaIn.value,this.value,resPanela);"><br>

    <input type="number"
      class="form-control form-control-lg"
      id="resPanela" name="resPanela" 
      onchange="calculo(this.value,preciopanela.value,RPanela,total);">
  </td>
  <input type="hidden" id="preciopanela" value="150">


  <td>
    <input type="text"
      class="form-control form-control-sm"
      id="RPanela" name="RPanela" value="0" readonly>
  </td>
```

> tengo dos funciones, resta y calculo. cada función individual funciona bien.

El problema que tengo es que la funcion calculo no reconoce la variable "cantidad" que es generada automaticamente por la funcion resta.

No se si sea js la mejor opcion para este calculo.
Muchas gracias por su tiempo

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. El planteamiento de tu pregunta no es claro, no se entiende qué es lo que no funciona exactamente. Puedes mejorar la pregunta [editándola](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/196627/edit), de modo que se pueda entender mejor.

Comment: De entrada tendrías que crear un HTML válido. También hay que tener en cuenta que **el valor `value` de un input es una cadena de texto**. Para poder sumar dos números tienes que utilizar `parseInt` si tus números son íntegros o `parseFloat` si tus números tienen decimales. Por ejemple en lugar de `subtotal = (precio * cantidad);`tienes que escribir `subtotal = (parseInt(precio) * parseInt(cantidad));`. Cada función individual funciona bien, porque si la utilizas por separado los argumentos que utilizas son números.

Answer (score 0):

Debes hacer un return en la función resta, luego creas una variable y le asignas como valor el llamado a esa función

```
function resta(numr, numr1, resultador) {

  return resultador.value = (numr - numr1);
}

let cant = resta(tus, parametros, aca)


function calculo(cantidad, precio, inputtext, totaltext) {

  gndtotal = totaltext.value - inputtext.value;


  subtotal = (precio * cantidad);
  inputtext.value = subtotal;

  total = eval(gndtotal);
  totaltext.value = total + subtotal;
}

let resuelto = calculo(cant, tus, parametros, aca)
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesa, entiendo que en "let cant = resta(tus, parametros, aca)" coloco los parametros de la Function resta, pero no me queda claro cuales parametros debo colocar en "let resuelto = calculo(cant, tus, parametros, aca)". Gracias por su tiempo

Comment: tu para llamar a tu función calculo le pasas unas variables como parámetro no?, y uno de esos parametros tiene que ser calculado con la función resta por lo que veo... bueno, primero ejecutas la función resta, y eso lo guardas en la variable cant (cantidad), para ser usado en la función de calculo, luego llamas a la función de calculo pasandole por parámetro cant y los otros parámetros que le debas ingresar

Comment: bueno lo e realizado como te he entendido. sigue sin funcionar



<script> 
function resta(numr, numr1, resultador) {

  return resultador.value = (numr - numr1);
}

let cant = resta(numr, numr1, resultador)


function calculo(cantidad, precio, inputtext, totaltext) {

  gndtotal = totaltext.value - inputtext.value;


  subtotal = (precio * cantidad);
  inputtext.value = subtotal;

  total = eval(gndtotal);
  totaltext.value = total + subtotal;
}

let resuelto = calculo(cant, precio, inputtext, totaltext)

</script>

Comment: Esta es la tabla html:
<input type="hidden" id="PanelaIn" name="PanelaIn" value="<?php echo $ver[3];  ?>" >

     <input type="number" id="Panela" name="Panela" placeholder="Saldo" required  onChange="resta(PanelaIn.value,this.value,resPanela);"><br>

      <input type="number"   id="resPanela" name="resPanela" onchange="calculo(this.value,preciopanela.value,RPanela,total);">
  </td>
  <input type="hidden" id="preciopanela"  value="150" >
  

 <td>
  <input type="text"  id="RPanela" name="RPanela"  value="0" readonly > 
sigue sin funcionar que habre echo mal??